# I cannot access to the login view after scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am developing a web application with ASP.NET Core 5 MVC.

I have created my own controllers and views and now I am trying to implement the identity views so I made scaffolding in my project and It created a new folder with the different views that Identity brings, but when my application is being executed I cannot access to any scaffolded view it shows me an error 404

These is my code in the `Startup` class

[image]

[image]

But when I try to access to the Login View:

[image]

And I also tried in this way:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` in your endpoint, Because the generated page is razor page, You need follow the route of razor page.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
         endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Comment: Hi @Kevin Alexis Martinez Herrera
, wait for your response. If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? If not, could you please follow up to let me know?